Laravel: Storing full path of image in database and showing it in the UI
I have uploaded an image in s3 bucket and attached a CloudFront distribution to that bucket. I have stored the full image path (which is a valid image) in my database. i.e.
https:/d3l9brpcqhhun7.cloudfront.net/outputs/media/8/Thumbnails/2024072710015766a4c595c6726.0000001.jpg

When I am trying to show it in the frontend using an img tag, it's not showing.
<img src="{{ $post->thumbnail_url }}" alt="thumbnail" class="w-1/2 mx-auto" />

I've inspected what is getting rendered in the UI (a livewire component). Also checked the Network request as well. In the network tab it is appending the APP_URL just before the image url. It's happening only in production. Not sure why?

I have tried putting the the full image URL hardcoded and it renders correctly. Also tried below approach but doesn't work.
<img :src="$post->thumbnail_url" alt="thumbnail" class="w-1/2 mx-auto" />

Any solution?

Thanks mate. You got sharp eyes. :100 I have just pasted that url in browser and it was working.

Yea. Browser automatically resolves the slash issue.
